# Wrong value when swapping array values in x86 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, quicksort

I'm working on quicksort in x86 assembly and I need to swap two elements of an array A[pivot] and A[j], but I can't even assign a value to an array index let alone swap the elements.

Array is assigned as such:

```
A:      .long   2,1,8,6,12
```

My original scheme of swapping didn't work at all so I reduced it to this to understand where my problem is. I've tried numerous ways to get the correct results, but all either result in the wrong value or a segmentation error

```
    movl    A(,%ebx,4), %eax            #eax = A[pivot]
    movl    A(,%edi,4), %edx            #edx = A[j]


                                        #ebx = pivot = 0
                                        #edi = j = 1

    pushl   %eax
    pushl   $test7                      #"A[pivot] = %d"
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp                    # A[0] = 2 

    pushl   %edx
    pushl   $test8                      #"A[j] = %d"
    call    printf
    addl    $8, %esp                   #A[1] = 1
```

This snippet returns:

```
A[pivot]         = 2 
A[j]             = -143535296
```

A[pivot] = A[0] = 2, so that is correct, but
A[j] = A[1] = 1

Is this the correct way to reference array elements when %ebx and %edi are two array indices to view their contents or change their values.

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

edit: Also, if I use A(,[index],4) as a printf argument it DOES display the right values.

edit1: I realize why my printf statements were incorrect, I changed to the code and it returned  what seem to be the right memory addresses. addr[A] = 134513652 and addr[A+1] = 134513656. My original problem of changing the values of an array still exists though, I continue to get a segmentation fault when performing this:

```
    leal    A(,%ebx,4), %ecx        # ecx = addr[A[0]]          
    movl    A(,%edi,4), %edx        # edx = A[1]
    movl    %edx, (%ecx)            # (ecx) = edx
```

Comment: Try some testing with opcode `leal` (load effective address, long) and see if you're getting addresses that are close to each other. I don't know how it would happen, but there might be some shenanigans with segment registers going on.

Comment: Your printf call is spoiling `edx`. Be careful about calling functions and either save volatile registers or use callee-saved ones like esi, edi, ebx.

Comment: I used 'leal A, %eax' and 'leal A, %edx' right after eachother with no displacement then printed %eax and %edx

Which gave me '%eax = 134513652 ', the correct address of A, and '%edx = -143224000 ' which is completely off. Something weird is definitely happening, I am solely using 32-bit registers if that is pertinent.

edit: Okay, didn't realize that printf would change the register  values that explains the result from the second printf call.

Comment: I got for the address `addr[A] = 134513652` and `addr[A+1] = 134513656 ` , so I suppose they are the correct memory addresses
 I then supposed I could do this to change a value   `leal A(,%ebx,4), %eax` `movl A(,%edi,4), %edx `
  `movl %edx, (%eax)`, but this just returns a segmentation fault.

Comment: OK. You've posted your debugging code, but what was the code you were using for the swap, the one that wasn't working?

Comment: Sorry, posted the code up as an edit to the original question. That's the code for just changing the value of A[j] to that of A[pivot].

Comment: It looks to me like you're mixing up addresses with data.  But there's not enough code in the last three lines that you show to really debug it.  What values are in ebx, ecx, edx, edi, etc when this code fragment starts?

Answer (score 1):

You should read about calling conventions esp. callee and caller save registers. On many ia32 calling conventions EAX, ECX and EDX are caller save register. That means a call - in your case the first printf call - may potentially change their value. It is called caller save because you as a caller are responsible for saving the value for example with push/pop instructions. Your example can also be fixed by using one of the callee saved registers.